# Maintain reference to raw tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am designing a database to store raw data from different financial sources. Database triggers will then be used to clean the raw data and insert it into a "normalized" data table. What is the best way to maintain the relationship from the clean data to the variety of data tables it came from?

What I've come up with so far are to have a separate table of {cleanID, rawTable, rawTableID}. The rawTable column would mark which table to look at and the rawTableID would mark which row in that table. I don't like this because you can't really maintain any referential integrity.

Alternatively, I could have a column in the raw tables which references the clean table. But, to find where a specific row in the clean table came from, I'd have to do a union over all the raw tables.

The raw tables all essentially hold the same information, but in different formats. They need to be kept raw for record keeping purposes. To make it easier on my application, I want to make one table that has all of the raw data, but normalised for easy interpretation, querying, etc. What would be the best way to maintain a link (in any form) from the clean, normalised data to the raw data row that it came from, keeping in mind that the raw data row may be a row from a bunch of tables? This is for auditing purposes.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if you think you could provide an answer based only on what you posted. Unless you provide some details about what you are trying to do this is going to lots of downvotes and probably get closed.

Comment: Here are a couple of great resources that will help you improve this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ or https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added some information about solutions I've thought of, but am interested in hearing others.

Comment: @Sam the problem isn't the solutions you thought. The question is unclear. It could describe an entire ETL project. `maintain the relationship from the clean data to the variety of data` what does that even mean? Are you talking about foreign keys? Or auditing fields?

Comment: what u meant by Raw table, do u mean it a `Staging table`, add sample 'raw` table  and `expected output table` and data type of the columns, we would be able to suggest a better solution

Comment: Ideally foreign keys, but I don't think that's possible given that you can't have a FK to multiple tables. What do you mean by auditing fields?

Comment: The raw tables all essentially hold the same information, but in different formats. They need to be kept raw for record keeping purposes. To make it easier on my application, I want to make one table that has all of the raw data, but normalised for easy interpretation, querying, etc. What would be the best way to maintain a link (in any form) from the clean, normalised data to the raw data row that it came from, keeping in mind that the raw data row may be a row from a bunch of tables? This is for auditing purposes.

Comment: Your question is so incredibly vague that nobody can answer this. My best guess is you could add an identity to the raw data table. Then add that identity as foreign key to every other row in all the other tables. But without ANY details this is just a shot in the dark. You seem to want an answer here but you have yet to post an answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam, best* is going to depend on too many factors that you haven't given us.

Here is an approach I've used with various data sources and similar data. It sounds like you want to be able to 'pull the thread' to validate the financial data.

Create a 'Raw' schema, dump the data as it is into this schema, setting up a source table per source.

I suggest this approach because I don't like to edit raw data, I like to be able to track back what was given to me.

Create a 'Staging' schema, make any transforms you want off the raw data into this table, here you will want to keep the previous PK (recordid & sourceid).

Finally a 'Prod' schema, where you will co-locate the data from different sources.

> Separate table  |  Same Table  |
>
> Source 1
>
> Raw - > Stage ->  | Prod |
>
> Source 2
>
> Raw - > Stage ->  | Prod |

RecordID and SourceID flow all the way through these tables, this is a composite key, this is your PK.

For tracking you'll also want to setup some dim/lookup tables for the sourceid. If you wanted to get creative based on the version of SQL Server, you could look into using sequenceID across the various source tables.

dim / lookup table is typically a meta data table that supports other tables.

In this instance I would create a table similar to this:

```
ID | Source
1  | Bob's Crazy Bike Town
2  | Wild Williez Fun store
3  | Swimmers Lane
```

Raw table for Source 1

```
RawTableID | SourceID
1          | 1
2          | 1
3          | 1
```

Raw table for Source 2

```
RawTableID | SourceID
1          | 2
2          | 2
3          | 2
```

The lookup table will allow you to store data about the sourceid and obviously a FK from the Raw table.

Comment: It is your world, you do as you want. Typically when you have data from different sources there are quirks, you need to do some Mastering of the data. Source1 has 'North Korea', Source2 has 'Korea, N' and you're creating an enterprise application, you want to display the ISO name 'Democratic People's Republic of Korea'. This is where you would make changes to the data for conformity, or normalization. -- Comment asked about why staging...

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by dim/lookup tables?